# Retaining HTML values (selected options, checkbox) when changin url between other components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one component that has some HTML code, with some select-options and dropdowns... this component i want it to be shared with other components, each component with a different URL. I made that works , but the thing is that when i go from one component to another(one url to another url), the selected options go back to their initial state... how can i make this works ??

**Shared Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-param-var',
  templateUrl: './param-var.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./param-var.component.scss']
})
export class ParamVarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  change(){

   var change = document.getElementById("oneseg");
                    if (change.innerHTML === "Desactivado")
                    {
                        change.innerHTML = "Activado";
                    }
                    else {
                        change.innerHTML = "Desactivado";
                    }
}

modo(value: string){
  switch(value) {
    case "mod1":
       console.log ("WORKS MODO 1");
       break;
    case "mod2":
        console.log ("WORKS MODO 2");
       break;
    case "mod3":
        console.log ("WORKS MODO 3");
       break;
  }
}

intGua(value : string) {
switch(value) {
    case "unCuarto":
       console.log ("WORKS 1/4");
       break;
    case "unOctavo":
        console.log ("WORKS 1/8");
       break;
    case "unDie":
        console.log ("WORKS 1/16");
       break;
    case "unTrein":
        console.log ("WORKS 1/32");
       break;
  }


}

}
```

**Shared Component HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                Parametros Variables
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Modo :</label>
                <select id="selectid" class="form-control-mb-12"
                ngModel (ngModelChange)="modo($event)">
                    <option value="mod1">MODO 1</option>
                    <option value="mod2">MODO 2</option>
                    <option value="mod3">MODO 3</option>
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <label>Intervalo de Guarda :</label>
                <select class="form-control-mb-12"
                (change)="intGua($event.target.value)">
                    <option value="unCuarto">1/4</option>
                    <option value="unOctavo">1/8</option>
                    <option value="unDie">1/16</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">1/32</option>
                </select> <br><br>
                One-Seg : <button (click)="change()" id="oneseg" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Desactivado</button>
                    <br><br><pre><h4>                Capa A Capa B Capa C</h4></pre>
                 <label>Nº de Segmentos[Ns]</label>   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select  class="form-control-mb-12" name="NSegcapaA" >
                    <option value="unCuarto">0   </option>
                    <option value="unOctavo">1     </option>
                    <option value="unDie">2     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">4     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">6     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">7     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">8     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">9     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">10     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">11     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">12     </option>
                    <option value="unTrein">13     </option>
                </select>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                    <option value="unCuarto">0</option>
                    <option value="unOctavo">1</option>
                    <option value="unDie">2</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">4</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">6</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">7</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">8</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">9</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">10</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">11</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">12</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">13</option>
                </select>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                  <option value="unCuarto">0</option>
                    <option value="unOctavo">1</option>
                    <option value="unDie">2</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">4</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">6</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">7</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">8</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">9</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">10</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">11</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">12</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">13</option>
                </select> <br><br>

                 <label>Esquema de Modulacion</label>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
            <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                    <option value="unOctavo">16-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unDie">64-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">DQPSK</option>
                </select> 
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                <option value="unOctavo">16-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unDie">64-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">DQPSK</option>
                </select> 
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                <option value="unOctavo">16-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unDie">64-QAM</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">DQPSK</option>
                </select> <br> <br>

                 <label>Codificacion Convolucional</label>  &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select class="form-control-mb-12">
               <option value="unOctavo">1/2</option>
                    <option value="unDie">2/3</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3/4</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5/6</option>
                </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
                  <option value="unOctavo">1/2</option>
                    <option value="unDie">2/3</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3/4</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5/6</option>
                </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <select class="form-control-mb-12">
               <option value="unOctavo">1/2</option>
                    <option value="unDie">2/3</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">3/4</option>
                    <option value="unTrein">5/6</option>
                </select> 

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="randomize()">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Shared Component Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { ParamVarRoutingModule } from './param-var-routing.module';
import { ParamVarComponent } from './param-var.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ParamVarRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ParamVarComponent,

  ],
  exports: [ParamVarComponent]
})
export class ParamVarModule { }
```

** One of the Component that Imports previous one.**

**Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { ResumenRoutingModule } from './resumen-routing.module';
import { ResumenComponent } from './resumen.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ParamVarModule} from '../param-var/param-var.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ResumenRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ParamVarModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ResumenComponent,


  ]
})
export class ResumenModule { }
```

**HTML**

```
<app-param-var></app-param-var>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-resumen',
  templateUrl: './resumen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resumen.component.scss']
})
export class ResumenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {



  }



}
```

Comment: Don't you need a service to keep the track ?

Comment: @Vega how can that be done? can u give me an example... how can i relate the html code to the service?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are referring to saving the state of a component.
Each time you change routes and switch between components, ngDestroy is called and therefore the state is not saved.

Basically, Angular has a **RouteReuseStrategy** which is an interface you can implement on your own to save states and reuse (see https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). But, this one will give you trouble if you have sibling/auxiliary components and not only parent-child level components (for now Angular team does not seem to have a solution or a plan to fix this, see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13869#issuecomment-294371551)

The other option which is available (it is a workaround and not so pretty) is to have a **service** which stores all your data and you can reuse it at any time.
Another idea (by kavi87 in github) is to have a router-outlet inside a parent component to store the state.

Hope this helped.

Comment: How can i tell my selected to stays in the value that is stored?

Comment: You need to create a service that will store your selected values. This can be done in many different ways - you can store your selection as component properties and on ngDestroy you can call the service to save it. Or if you can reach them using DOM elements and store their values in that service.

Comment: i understand when you say to save the data in the service . but i don know how to keep the option selected in the view in  the html code .

Comment: If you will save the selected values, when you initialize the component (ngOnInit) you will have to check for saved data in your service and restore it which includes also setting the selected values/texts etc. in your form data.  You should also consider using [Redux ngx-store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)